# How can I select the whole row of a listview?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a listview with lots of ListviewColumns and 2 checkboxes. The checkboxes turn each other off. I would like to select the whole row with a click on one of the two checkboxes either to be able to use the content later. So far this is only possible when I click with the mouse on the corresponding row.
How can I set the SelectedItem in the code, best with the checkboxes?

```
            <ListView Margin="6,2,160,50" Name="EditorList" FontFamily="Calibri" Background="Silver" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                      MouseWheel="EditorList_MouseWheel" MouseRightButtonUp="EditorList_MouseRightButtonDown" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="EditorList_SelectionChanged" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Image" Width="60" >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=ImageSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="1" Stretch="Uniform" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Position X" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Position[0], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Position Y" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Position[1], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Position Z" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Position[2], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Rotation X" Width="75"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Rotation[0], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Rotation Y" Width="75"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Rotation[1], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Rotation Z" Width="75"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Rotation[2], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Scale X" Width="75"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Scale[0], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Scale Y" Width="75"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Scale[1], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Scale Z" Width="75"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Scale[2], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Material" Width="75"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Material, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="To Do" Width="100">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel" Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <CheckBox Content="Delete" Tag="{Binding ElementName=stackpanel}" IsThreeState="False" Name="toD" Checked="ToD_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ToDelete, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTip="delete this item" />
                                        <CheckBox Content="Change" Tag="{Binding ElementName=stackpanel}" IsThreeState="False" Name="toC" Checked="ToC_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ToChange, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTip="change to another item" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

```
       private void ToD_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is CheckBox cbSender)
            {
                if (cbSender.Tag is StackPanel stackpanel)
                {
                    if (stackpanel.FindName("toC") is CheckBox cb1)
                    {
                        cb1.IsChecked = !cbSender.IsChecked;
                    }
                    ComboChangeItem.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
        }
        private void ToC_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is CheckBox cbSender)
            {
                if (cbSender.Tag is StackPanel stackPanel)
                {
                    if (stackPanel.FindName("toD") is CheckBox cb)
                    {
                        cb.IsChecked = !cbSender.IsChecked;
                    }
                    ComboChangeItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
        }
```

(This is how my listview looks, the number of objects may vary.)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhpDG.jpg)

I haven't really tried lots of things because I don't know where to start.

Edit: I found by myself a solution:

```
                    EditorObjects selectedItem = EditorList.ItemsSource.Cast<EditorObjects>().First(a => a.ToChange);
                if (selectedItem != null)
                {
                    EditorList.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried by using the SelectedItem property in your ListView? `SelectedItem="{Binding Path=YourSelectedItem}"`

Comment: I don't know what are you mean with YourSelectedItem. 
I tried a lot Bindings with the SelectedItem property in the Listview which returns in a Binding Error